TouchableOpacity styling with className doesn't render
So I've been banging my head on this for a while now and I don't understand why it the touchable opacity just won't render it style (using tailwind). Here is my code
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Poppins_400Regular, Poppins_600SemiBold } from '@expo-google-fonts/poppins';
import React from 'react'

const CustomButton = ({ title, handlePress, containerStyle, textStyles, isLoading }) => {
  
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Poppins_400Regular,
    Poppins_600SemiBold,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null; // Or return a loading component
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={handlePress}
      activeOpacity={0.7}
      className='bg-main rounded-xl min-h-[62px] justify-center items-center'
    >
      <Text className='font-poppins text-lg text-white'>Custom Button</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>  
  );
}


export default CustomButton

I followed the nativewind setup for both typescript nativewind 4+ and yet it still won't work as expected. Updated everything. The view and text do render their style, but not touchableOpacity. Here is my package.json:
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/orbitron": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^8.0.8",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.18",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.18",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "nativewind": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^11.0.12",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.6",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },

Please. I'm so done with this.
Again, I followed the guide for nativewind 4+ with typescript, updated expo, etc.
